# Don't Israeli women fast?

Tags: women, eretz-yisrael, fast-days, modern-times, demography

More than one Israeli has told me that women in Israel don't fast. More specifically, that a large percentage of otherwise observant (healthy, non-pregnant, non-nursing) Jewish women in Israel do not fast on the Jewish public fasts (with the exception of 9 *Av* and *Yom Kipur*, when they do fast). Note that this was said about women only: observant men do fast.

Does anyone have statistics or any indication of the extent to which this is true? For example, have any *pos'kim* or (*l'havdil*) magazine articles mentioned it as a common trend?

Specific statistics would be ideal.

#### Related question

- [Why don't Israeli women fast?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63949/why-dont-israeli-women-fast)

Comment: VTC as about Jews not Judaism?

Comment: @mevaqesh It's about omitting the (Judaism) practice of fasting on a (Judaism) fast day. How much more about Judaism can it be?

Comment: It appears to be asking about statistics of Jews, in contradistinction to your other question which asks for religious justification.

Comment: @mevaqesh I'm glad my intent came through to the written word. May all our efforts be similarly crowned with success.